# ¿Alguien sabe como contar caracteres repetidos de manera consecutiva en c#?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Tengo que hacer una validacion para nombres, debo tomar el texto de un TextBox y verificar que no se repitan mas de 3 letras de manera consecutiva, por ejemplo: Aaaaaaro, Maaaaaradiaga, rrrrodriguez, Darwin Perezzzz. Esos ejemplos deberian ser invalidos sin embargo no logre validar que fueran caracteres consecutivos los que se contara.

Estuve probando pero lo mas que logre es que contara cuantas veces se repite cada letra, poer no funcionaba para saber si eran consecutivas o no, ya que podria escribir "Alcantara" y lo tomaria como un nombre invalido ya que tiene 4 veces la letra "a" pero no esta de manera consecutiva.

```
public void validar(string cadena)
    {
        var result = from a in cadena.ToUpper().ToCharArray().Where(Char.IsLetter)
                     group a by a into g
                     select new
                     {
                         Letra = g.Key,
                         Repeticiones = g.Count()
                     };
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            if (item.Repeticiones >=4 )
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Una letra se repite mas de 3 veces: " + item.Letra.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No repiten");
            }
        }
    }
```

Ese fue el codigo que use para contar los caracteres, sin embargo no me funciona para lo que necesito. Si alguien tiene una idea se lo agradeceria mucho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podrías crear un función de esta manera

```
public bool TieneLetraRepetida(string texto, int ocurrencias = 4)
{
    char l = char.MinValue;
    string textoUpper= texto.ToUpper();
    int contador = 1;
    foreach(char c in textoUpper)
    {
        if(c == l) contador++;
        else contador = 1;

        if(contador>=ocurrencias) return true;
        l = c;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me sirvio

Answer (score 1):

Me parece que usar Linq hace más complicado el código.

Sugiero que introduzcas una variable que recuerde el caracter anterior, una que cuente cuántas veces se repite y recorras el arreglo:

```
char cAnterior = 0;
int veces = 0;

for (char c in cadena.ToUpper()){
    if (c == cAnterior){
        if (veces++ > 3){
            // Un caracter se repite más de 3 veces
        }
    }
    else {
        cAnterior = c;
        veces = 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Igualmente, muchas gracias, no habia pensado en guardar ese el caracter anterior